# XPath OR, alternative

Tags: c#, xpath, html-agility-pack

I use CSharp, XPath and HTMLAgility Pack. I use XPath strings such as:

```
"//table[3]/td[1]/span[2]/text() | //table[6]/td[1]/span[2]/text()"
"//table[8]/td[1]/span[2]/text() | //table[10]/td[1]/span[2]/text()"
```

The difference is only in table numbers. Is it possible to use some other XPath function to replace the XPath or `|`?

What I actually do: With the first XPath string (where I have table numbers 3 & 6) I extract one value. With the second XPath string (where i have table numbers are 8 & 10) I extract another value.

And additional question about performance - is the XPath string `//table[8]/td[1]/span[2]/text()` faster than the XPath string with `OR` `//table[8]/td[1]/span[2]/text() | //table[10]/td[1]/span[2]/text()`? I ask this because I have many many XPath strings for many many values and if there is a difference which really means I need to try something else. I can't do the measurement right now that's why I ask you this question to share your experience.

Comment: Why not just use [3|6] instead of the whole or?

Comment: @Yet: That wouldn't even be a valid XPath then.  You could only use OR between two node sets, not just any arbitrary expression.

Comment: You can use other XPATH expression if the Html allows it. Could you share some Html code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Firstly, `//table[6]` looks odd. Are you sure you don't mean `(//table)[6]`? (The first selects every table that is the 6th child of its parent; the second selects the sixth table in the document.) I will assume the latter.

In XPath 2.0 you can write

```
(//table)[position()=(3,6,8,10)]/td[1]/span[2]/text()
```

In 1.0 that would have to be

```
(//table)[position()=3 or position()=6 or position()=8 or position()=10]
    /td[1]/span[2]/text()
```

Or (in either release) you could write

```
((//table)[3] | (//table)[6] | (//table)[8] | (//table)[10])/td[1]/span[2]/text()
```

Your question about performance can't be answered without knowing what XPath implementation you are using.

Comment: Thanks for all answers. How to know what version of XPath i'm using? What you mean by "knowing what XPath implementation you are using"? I use XPath with CSharp and HTMLAgilityPack

Comment: If I don't have XPath 2.0, how can i install it?